# Specific query in using a field from another databse in a insert - select clause - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select, sql-insert

My SQL Server query looks like this:

```
USE Manus_Menon
GO

INSERT INTO Manus_Menon.dbo.Commodity_Fill_Rate (NO_OF_MISSES)
   SELECT COUNT(Part_Number) 
   FROM Outsource_Data.dbo.GLOBAL_BACKLOG 
   WHERE Order_Creation_Date >= '2015-02-23' 
     AND Order_Creation_Date <= '2015-02-27'  
     AND Part_Number = Manus_Menon.dbo.Commodity_Fill_Rate.PARTNUM;
GO
```

The error I'm getting is :

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
>   The multi-part identifier "Manus_Menon.dbo.Commodity_Fill_Rate.PARTNUM" could not be bound.

Both databases mentioned are on the same physical server.

Kindly help me out with this. Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Comment: can you give alias name COUNT(Part_Number) as PartNumber and where comes the Part_Number = Manus_Menon.dbo.Commodity_Fill_Rate.PARTNUM in end condition if you join with Commodity_Fill_Rate table then you can use in filter condition

Comment: You Table Commodity_Fill_Rate is part of Insert statement, not select.

Comment: Hi guys. the thing is i want for each part number in Commodity fill rate table the count of occurences of that part number in the global backlog table populated in NO_OF _MISSES column in Commodity Fill Rate table. I hope this sheds some more light on the origin of this query.

Comment: you need to join `Manus_Menon.dbo.Commodity_Fill_Rate` into your select. and i think, you'll want to select 2 columns, the Manus_Menon.dbo.Commodity_Fill_Rate.PARTNUM and the count.

Answer (score 0):

This is what finally worked for me:

```
SELECT CFR.PARTNUM,COUNT(GBL.Part_Number) 
FROM Manus_Menon.dbo.Commodity_Fill_Rate CFR 
INNER JOIN Outsource_Data.dbo.GLOBAL_BACKLOG GBL
ON CFR.PARTNUM = GBL.Part_Number
WHERE GBL.Order_Creation_Date >= '2015-02-23'
AND GBL.Order_Creation_Date <= '2015-02-27'
GROUP BY CFR.PARTNUM
```

Thank you for your time.